# Pytorch: Is there an issue in the forward pass when I reassign a variable with a new value?

Tags: pytorch

I am new with pytorch and I have an issue when I try to train the network from this great work https://github.com/Jiahao-UTS/SLPT-master.

When I modify the forward pass of the SLPT like follow, the training is stable very fast (arround NME = 30%)

```
        # stage_1
        ROI_anchor_1, bbox_size, start_anchor = self.ROI_1(initial_landmarks.detach())
        ROI_anchor_1 = ROI_anchor_1.view(bs, self.num_point * self.Sample_num * self.Sample_num, 2)
        ROI_feature_1 = self.interpolation(feature_map, ROI_anchor_1.detach()).view(bs, self.num_point, self.Sample_num,
                                                                            self.Sample_num, self.d_model)
        ROI_feature_1 = ROI_feature_1.view(bs * self.num_point, self.Sample_num, self.Sample_num,
                                     self.d_model).permute(0, 3, 2, 1)

        transformer_feature_1 = self.feature_extractor(ROI_feature_1).view(bs, self.num_point, self.d_model)

        offset_1 = self.Transformer(transformer_feature_1)
        offset_1 = self.out_layer(offset_1)

        landmarks_1 = start_anchor.unsqueeze(1) + bbox_size.unsqueeze(1) * offset_1
        output_list.append(landmarks_1)

        # stage_2
        ROI_anchor_2, bbox_size, start_anchor = self.ROI_2(landmarks_1[:, -1, :, :].detach())
        ROI_anchor_2 = ROI_anchor_2.view(bs, self.num_point * self.Sample_num * self.Sample_num, 2)
        ROI_feature_2 = self.interpolation(feature_map, ROI_anchor_2.detach()).view(bs, self.num_point, self.Sample_num,
                                                                                 self.Sample_num, self.d_model)
        ROI_feature_2 = ROI_feature_2.view(bs * self.num_point, self.Sample_num, self.Sample_num,
                                           self.d_model).permute(0, 3, 2, 1)

        transformer_feature_2 = self.feature_extractor(ROI_feature_2).view(bs, self.num_point, self.d_model)

        offset_2 = self.Transformer(transformer_feature_2)
        offset_2 = self.out_layer(offset_2)

        landmarks_2 = start_anchor.unsqueeze(1) + bbox_size.unsqueeze(1) * offset_2
        output_list.append(landmarks_2)

        # stage_3
        ROI_anchor_3, bbox_size, start_anchor = self.ROI_3(landmarks_2[:, -1, :, :].detach())
        ROI_anchor_3 = ROI_anchor_3.view(bs, self.num_point * self.Sample_num * self.Sample_num, 2)
        ROI_feature_3= self.interpolation(feature_map, ROI_anchor_3.detach()).view(bs, self.num_point, self.Sample_num,
                                                                                   self.Sample_num, self.d_model)
        ROI_feature_3 = ROI_feature_3.view(bs * self.num_point, self.Sample_num, self.Sample_num,
                                           self.d_model).permute(0, 3, 2, 1)

        transformer_feature_3 = self.feature_extractor(ROI_feature_3).view(bs, self.num_point, self.d_model)

        offset_3 = self.Transformer(transformer_feature_3)
        offset_3 = self.out_layer(offset_3)

        landmarks_3 = start_anchor.unsqueeze(1) + bbox_size.unsqueeze(1) * offset_3
        output_list.append(landmarks_3)
```

And it doesn't converge to the expected results (arround NME = 4.1%). But if I don't change the original code, the training converge to the expected results.

So, my question is why the training result is different in this two case?

I try to train the network with reassign some variables in the forward pass.

Comment: Can you point out the difference between your code and the original one?

Comment: Sure, I change the "start_anchor_1", "start_anchor_2", "start_anchor_3", " bbox_size_1", "bbox_size_2" and "bbox_size_3" variables to the "start_anchor" and "bbox_size". These are the only differences between these two codes, I don't understand why this reassignment modify the training result.